# NSURLSessionでPHPにGETしてレスポンスをUIWebViewで表示

Tags: ios, objective-c, php

iOSアプリケーションからNSURLSessionを利用してクエリをPHPにGETし、レスポンス(HTML)をアプリケーション上のUIWebViewで表示したいと考えております。

PHPからのレスポンスはNSURLResponseの中にHTMLがテキストとして入ってると思うのですが、そのデータをUIWebViewに渡して表示するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ぐぐったらでてきました。`UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL`でどうでしょう？

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLResponse`自体にはHTMLのテキストは入っていません。
`NSURLSessionDataTask`に設定したコールバックの引数からデータが取得できます。

テキストのエンコーディングについては`NSURLResponse`から取得する必要があります。

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask* task =
[session dataTaskWithURL:url
       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

         // エンコーディングを取得してテキストに変換
         CFStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)[response textEncodingName]);
         NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(encoding)];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // WebViewにHTMLを表示
           [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[response URL]];
         });
       }];

// ダウンロード開始
[task resume];
```

参考ページ: http://chicketen.blog.jp/archives/1256068.html